# Unable to start my spring boot application with Oracle

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot, oracle10g

I just created a spring boot application and here are the dependency that I added:

[image: dependency]

the problem is that when i try to run my application, the following error is displayed:

```
> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report
> re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 2020-05-28 14:45:46.344
> ERROR 29812 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication          
> : Application run failed
> 
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor'
> defined in class path resource
> [org/springframework/boot/devtools/autoconfigure/DevToolsDataSourceAutoConfiguration.class]:
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method
> 'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor' parameter 0; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]:
> Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method
> 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class:
> oracle.jdbc.driver.oracleDriver   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:539)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108)
> ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
> ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
> ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143)
> ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)
> [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)
> [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
> [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
> [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)
> [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
> [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]     at
> com.app.habilitation.ProjetGestionHabilitationApplication.main(ProjetGestionHabilitationApplication.java:10)
> [classes/:na]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> ~[na:1.8.0_111]   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> ~[na:1.8.0_111]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> ~[na:1.8.0_111]   at
> org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
> [spring-boot-devtools-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE] Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]:
> Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method
> 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class:
> oracle.jdbc.driver.oracleDriver   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:636)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1306)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1226)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   ... 27 common frames
> omitted Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method
> 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class:
> oracle.jdbc.driver.oracleDriver   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   ... 41 common frames
> omitted Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver
> class: oracle.jdbc.driver.oracleDriver    at
> org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:94)
> ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.determineDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:223)
> ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder(DataSourceProperties.java:175)
> ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration.createDataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:43)
> ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.dataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:85)
> ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> ~[na:1.8.0_111]   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> ~[na:1.8.0_111]   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> ~[na:1.8.0_111]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> ~[na:1.8.0_111]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   ... 42 common frames
> omitted
```

I looked a little on the internet and I found that you have to add the oracle driver in the application.properties file and that's what I have here is the code of my application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.oracleDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl
spring.datasource.username=nawfel       
spring.datasource.password=hr
```

but that did not solve my problem, it is the first time that I use oracle with spring boot therefore it is possible that there are a few things which escape me especially since I am always a beginner in this field :(

and here is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>habilitation</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Projet gestion habilitation</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

can some one help me please ??

Comment: Did you add oracle driver to your pom/jar file? Is the class-name correct? Shouldn't it be oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver with a uppercase "O"?

Comment: hello, yes I added the dependency of oracle in my pom.xml file (I added the pom.xml file in my question above if you want to see it in full) for what concerns oracle here is the dependency that i added: <dependency>
   <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
   <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>

Comment: Have you tried changing to spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver with an uppercase "O"?

Comment: yes but it gives me a new error different from this one, here is the new error: java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

Comment: Always connect to the SERVICE_NAME exposed by the Oracle Database.  spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/orcl  (note the forslash instead of colon.)

Comment: it works thank you very much !!!